# Laravel Eloquent Fetch the logs that only belong to users who are belongs to shop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 3 Models like this

users

> belongs to shop

logs

> belongs to user

shop

now I need to fetch only the logs of the users that are only belong to shop

Here's my query but incomplete

```
Logs::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($shop_id) {
 $q->shop()->where('shop.id', $shop_id);
})->get();
```

But doesn't succeed.

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you post up your models? Also, I'm assuming you've read through Laravel's [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship documentation?

Comment: Make it reverse: `Shop::where(['id' => $shop_id])->with(['users', 'users.logs'])->first();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
  $logs=Logs::whereHas('user',function ($query) use ($shopId) {
   $query->whereHas('shop',function ($query) use ($shopId) {
       $query->where('id',$shopId);
   });
  })->get();
```

**Notice:** you said any log belongs to a user, in that case you have to call

> Log::whereHas('user')

instead of

> Log::whereHas('users')